# WebStorm2017.2.4: The module already in package.json, but the it still show "Module is not listed in package.json dependencies"

Tags: webstorm

I installed the react-native and save it into the package.json, but the web storm still show the warning when I import react-native, the detail is:
[image]

[image]

Comment: does the problem persist after caches invalidation (File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart)?

Comment: It fixed the problem, thank you so much

Comment: @lena That did not fix the problem for me. Even more: if I tell WebStorm to add the dependendency to `package.json`, it will add a duplicated dependency, and *still*  will complain that it is not listed in package.json. I can then repeat the process, adding line after line in the package.json, and still nothing good comes out of it :)